# How does Facebook authentication work in comments?

Tags: architecture, facebook-comments

Thinking on the architecture of my new javascript plugin for websites, I want to integrate user authentication in a manner similar to what Facebook is doing in its Comments plugin.

In Comments, when the user is logged-in to Facebook, **every site** that implements Comments will allow the site's visitor to comment. On the contrary, when the user is not logged-in to Facebook, an authentication is required, but only once!

I'm interested to know how is this done, considering that cookies and web-storage is per domain?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** They use an iframe.

When Facebook's user is logged into Facebook, an authentication mechanism is activated (like a cookie) and attached to www.facebook.com's domain.

Every page with their Comments plugin has an `<ifram>` tag whose source is www.facebook.com. This iframe, being a page of its own, sends the stored authentication to Facebook's domain - thus keeping the domain separation.

*The comments area is actually facebook.com*, and since the user is logged-in - the avatar is shown.

Implementation of a plugin with similar behavior requires this kind architecture.